# How to store file in Android which I want edit later?

Tags: android, file, storage, application-cache

I have a `.vcf` file and I want to put it in Android so I can read it from my code. The problem is that I cannot put it into assets folder, because I want to overwrite/edit this file later. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First since you might want to load it via code, you may need to include the `.vcf` file in `/assets` folder just for loading.

Then you can copy the `.vcf` file to the device's internal or external storage for doing overwrite/edit operation on the fly.

For more information about the internal and external storage, please refer to [Android Developers: Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I thought about it and hoped that there is other way. I guess not. Thanks than

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in the phone's internal memory using [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and next edit it using FileOutputStream too. If you only want to read it, you can use [FileInputStrem](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instead.

You can save the file in the assets folder and when you open the app, save it as I have just said.